# How do I change the interval type of the DATEADD function in PowerBI dynamically?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to give my users the ability to select whether to compare current data with data from either the previous month or year. This DAX measure is written in PowerBI. The following snippet of code uses the user's selection of 'MarketShare' and 'Match' to determine the calculation and the user's selection of 'Compare' to determine whether to compare with the previous month or year but is not efficient because I repeat the 'ScriptTypeVar' variable for the month and year versions.

```
Previous Amount Scripted = 
VAR SelectedMatch = FIRSTNONBLANK(Match[Match],1)
VAR SelectedMarketShare = FIRSTNONBLANK('Market Share'[Market Share],1)
VAR SelectedCompare = FIRSTNONBLANK('Compare'[Compare],1)


VAR PreviousMonthScriptTypeVar = SWITCH(TRUE(),
                SelectedMarketShare = "Quantity", CALCULATE(SUM(Scripts_Fact[Pack Quantity]),DATEADD('Date_Dimension'[Date], -1, ,MONTH)),
                SelectedMarketShare = "Quantity (Repeats)", CALCULATE(SUM(Scripts_Fact[Pack Quantity (Repeats)]),DATEADD('Date_Dimension'[Date], -1, ,MONTH)),
                SelectedMarketShare = "Value", CALCULATE(SUM(Scripts_Fact[Value]),DATEADD('Date_Dimension'[Date], -1, ,MONTH)),
                SelectedMarketShare = "Value (Repeats)", CALCULATE(SUM(Scripts_Fact[Value (Repeats)]),DATEADD('Date_Dimension'[Date], -1, ,MONTH))
            )

VAR PreviousYearScriptTypeVar = SWITCH(TRUE(),
                SelectedMarketShare = "Quantity", CALCULATE(SUM(Scripts_Fact[Pack Quantity]),DATEADD('Date_Dimension'[Date], -1, ,YEAR)),
                SelectedMarketShare = "Quantity (Repeats)", CALCULATE(SUM(Scripts_Fact[Pack Quantity (Repeats)]),DATEADD('Date_Dimension'[Date], -1, ,YEAR)),
                SelectedMarketShare = "Value", CALCULATE(SUM(Scripts_Fact[Value]),DATEADD('Date_Dimension'[Date], -1, ,YEAR)),
                SelectedMarketShare = "Value (Repeats)", CALCULATE(SUM(Scripts_Fact[Value (Repeats)]),DATEADD('Date_Dimension'[Date], -1, ,YEAR))
            )

VAR CompareTypeVar = SWITCH(TRUE(),
                SelectedCompare = "Previous Month", PreviousMonthScriptTypeVar,
                SelectedCompare = "Same Month Previous Year", PreviousYearScriptTypeVar
            )


VAR AmountScriptedVar = 
IF(AND(HASONEVALUE('Calendar'[Year]),HASONEVALUE('Calendar'[Month])),
                                SWITCH(TRUE(),
                                    SelectedMatch = "A", CALCULATE(CompareTypeVar,USERELATIONSHIP('Reporting_Products'[A], Product_Dimension[A])),
                                    SelectedMatch = "B", CALCULATE(CompareTypeVar,USERELATIONSHIP(Reporting_Products[B], Product_Dimension[B])),
                                    SelectedMatch = "C", CALCULATE(CompareTypeVar,USERELATIONSHIP('Reporting_Products'[C], Product_Dimension[C])),
                                    SelectedMatch = "D", CALCULATE(CompareTypeVar,USERELATIONSHIP('Reporting_Products'[D], Product_Dimension[D]))
                                    ),
                                [AmountScripted]
                            )
RETURN
AmountScriptedVar
```

I tried to use the 'CompareTypeVar' switch to return either MONTH or YEAR keywords and simplify the measurement as follows:

```
Previous Amount Scripted = 
VAR SelectedMatch = FIRSTNONBLANK(Match[Match],1)
VAR SelectedMarketShare = FIRSTNONBLANK('Market Share'[Market Share],1)
VAR SelectedCompare = FIRSTNONBLANK('Compare'[Compare],1)

VAR CompareTypeVar = SWITCH(TRUE(),
                SelectedCompare = "Previous Month", MONTH,
                SelectedCompare = "Same Month Previous Year", YEAR
            )

VAR ScriptTypeVar = SWITCH(TRUE(),
                SelectedMarketShare = "Quantity", CALCULATE(SUM(Scripts_Fact[Pack Quantity]),DATEADD('Date_Dimension'[Date], -1, ,CompareTypeVar)),
                SelectedMarketShare = "Quantity (Repeats)", CALCULATE(SUM(Scripts_Fact[Pack Quantity (Repeats)]),DATEADD('Date_Dimension'[Date], -1, ,CompareTypeVar)),
                SelectedMarketShare = "Value", CALCULATE(SUM(Scripts_Fact[Value]),DATEADD('Date_Dimension'[Date], -1, ,CompareTypeVar)),
                SelectedMarketShare = "Value (Repeats)", CALCULATE(SUM(Scripts_Fact[Value (Repeats)]),DATEADD('Date_Dimension'[Date], -1, ,CompareTypeVar))
            )               

VAR AmountScriptedVar = IF(AND(HASONEVALUE('Calendar'[Year]),HASONEVALUE('Calendar'[Month])),
                                SWITCH(TRUE(),
                                    SelectedMatch = "Generic Code", CALCULATE(ScriptTypeVar,USERELATIONSHIP('Reporting_Products'[Medprax Generic Code], Product_Dimension[Medprax Generic Code])),
                                    SelectedMatch = "ATC5 Code", CALCULATE(ScriptTypeVar,USERELATIONSHIP(Reporting_Products[ATC5 Code], Product_Dimension[ATC5 Code])),
                                    SelectedMatch = "ATC4 Code", CALCULATE(ScriptTypeVar,USERELATIONSHIP('Reporting_Products'[ATC4 Code], Product_Dimension[ATC4 Code])),
                                    SelectedMatch = "ATM Link", CALCULATE(ScriptTypeVar,USERELATIONSHIP('Reporting_Products'[ATM Link], Product_Dimension[ATM Link]))
                                    ),
                                [AmountScripted]
                            )
RETURN
AmountScriptedVar
```

...but I get the following error:

```
The last argument must be one of these keywords: DAY, MONTH, QUARTER, or YEAR.
```

I have searched but can't find a solution to dynamically change the interval keyword. I also tried using an if statement within the DATEADD function to return the Keywords directly without using a variable, but that returned the same error. Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Although the initial version works, future projects may give the user more selections and would require more dummy variables to be coded. It would be ideal if each user selection could be handled by a switch statement and combined to create a final calculation as shown in the second version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible to make that last argument a variable. I'd suggest the following approach instead.

```
Previous Amount Scripted =
<...>
VAR CompareDatesTable =
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        SelectedCompare = "Previous Month",
        DATEADD ( 'Date_Dimension'[Date], -1, MONTH ),
        SelectedCompare = "Same Month Previous Year",
        DATEADD ( 'Date_Dimension'[Date], -1, YEAR)
    )
VAR ScriptTypeVar =
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        SelectedMarketShare = "Quantity",
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( Scripts_Fact[Pack Quantity] ),
            CompareDatesTable
        ),
        <...>
    )
<...>
```

In the above, I am passing an entire table `CompareDatesTable` into the `CALCULATE` function.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried that method as per your suggestion and recieved an error. 

**The True/False expression does not specify a column. Each True/False expressions used as a table filter expression must refer to exactly one column.**

I encountered this error before posting the question and tried to avoid it by returning only the interval, which did not work either.

Comment: That's odd. It definitely worked when I tested it on some of my own data. Can you share sample data or files where I can reproduce the error?